# How can I see data from an already made mysql database on Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I am trying to use a mysql database created and filled with data by someone else

I created a model with the same name as the table I want to get data from, my models is as follows

```
class Study(models.Model):
study_name =        models.TextField(default='Unknown')
description = models.TextField(default='Unknown')
language =    models.TextField(default='Unknown')
number_of_years = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

database connected but when I go to admin I don't see the data there

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step by step solution would be:

1. get the name of the table containing your data, I'll call it `study_table`
2. make sure you know how the table was defined so you can match it with django model definition. Connect to the database with a MySQL client and run the following query:

   ```sql
   DESCRIBE study_table;
   ```
3. based on the table name, column types and column names, define your model to match everything. Django models do a lot of automated naming so you have force the naming to make sure your model matches your database. Principles are:

   - Specify the [table name as a meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#db-table) option.
   - Create fields with names matching column names and [field types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#field-types) matching column types. Taking an example from your code, the field `study_name` should match a column with the same name in the table `study_table`.

   ```
   class Study(models.Model):
   study_name = models.TextField(default='Unknown')
   description = models.TextField(default='Unknown')
   language = models.TextField(default='Unknown')
   number_of_years = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   class Meta:
       db_table = study_table
   ```

   Side note: your `IntegerField` has a default as a string `'0'`.
4. making sure the app (I'll call it `study_app`) containing your model is enabled, the database is configure properly in your django settings, try to access data from the admin shell (`python manage.py shell`):

   ```py
   >>> from study_app.models import Study
   >>> Study.objects.first()
   ```

   This should return an answer, if it does not, your model doesn't match the database data.
5. to make accessing the data easier, create an [admin page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) as suggested by @iklinac. You can now read, edit your data through your browser.

A few suggestions you could consider:

- `study_name` should probably be a `models.CharField(max_length=255)` or similar
- `description` should be allowed to be empty `models.TextField(blank=True)`
- `language` should probably be a `models.CharField` with a [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) option.

Answer (score 1):

You should create [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) instance for your model

> The ModelAdmin class is the representation of a model in the admin
>   interface. Usually, these are stored in a file named admin.py in your
>   application.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Study

class StudyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Study, StudyAdmin)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a MySQL database with tables of data that don't have models created yet, you can use the `dumpdata` command to automatically generate the models:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata

Then, you can register those models in the Django admin. `dumpdata` should only be used as a starting point, since they are auto-generated and won't contain many of Django's data integrity features.

Good luck!